# Python cashier without db

Tags: python

so i have this mission to build a python cashier program using only python. without db use.
i use the dict and keys method to build it.
so i have 2 questions:

1. can i get an idea how to keep the program running after the moneybalance part, while i'm still saving the current moneybalance status? like, to make it an continuous program and not just one time.
2. i would like to get overall review on how is the idea for this mission, how it's written, and etc. would you do it in other way? if so i would like to hear how.
   remember, my mission is to build python cashier without any outside libraries\db's.

Code:

```
print('welcome to python cashier')
money = int(input('enter cashier current money\n'))


prices = {"small popcorn" : 3, "medium popcorn" : 5,
             "large popcorn" : 8, "small drink" : 1,
              "medium drink" : 2, "large drink" : 3 }
 

def calc(money, prices):
      try:
         itemchange = pay - itemvalue  
      except Exception as e:
        print(e)
      finally:
        print(f'change: {itemchange}') 

def show(money, prices): 
     try:
         for key,value in prices.items():
            print (f'{key}: {value}')
     except Exception as e:
         print(e)
     finally:
         return False
show(money, prices)

def start(money, prices):
     try:
     
        for key, value in prices.items():
          global item
          item = str(input('enter what you want to buy:\n'))
          if (item in prices.keys()):
            global itemvalue
            itemvalue = prices.get(item)
            print(f'{item}: {itemvalue}')
            global pay
            pay = float(input('how much costumer pay?\n'))
            return calc(money, prices)
          else:
            print('item not found')
     except Exception as e:
           print(e)
     finally:
           moneybalance = money + itemvalue
           print(f'moneybalance: {moneybalance}')
              

start(money, prices)
```

Comment: this sounds very much like a school assignment. If so, can you post the actual assignment details? I think I get where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

1. The real question is if someone asked you to save the information. As you said they asked in the mission to do this without a database I don't think you need to do that. Btw if it's without an actual database you can use just .txt files to save information. Check about the "open" function in Python.

Quick Example:

```
with open('save.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(str(cash)) # cash is an integer.
```

It's an example of writing a file. Btw I don't think they wanted you to save the information. Check it before you're applying something to don't ruin your work :).

2. I would suggest to put all the declarations of variables at the start of the script and add a "main" function. Call the main function from **name** == '**main**'. Too I recommend you to do a more detailed function names. Try not to use global variables in this small code (you can declare it at the start, it'll be global and more easy to read your code and understand it faster). I think in your first question you thought about making your program run more than one time in any program run? Read about Python Loops if I'm correct :). Too you wrapped your input return with str() and it useless, because the returned value from input is already str (String type).

Quick Example:

```
# Variables Declaration (Just an example for the structure).
ABC = 0
cash = 1000

# Functions Declaration
def calculate_price(money, prices):
    # Code Here.
    pass

def main():
    # The code of your start function, you don't need and arguments for this.
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main() # Call main here.
```

In this way your code will be readable and comfort to analyze :).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like an assignment than an actual problem.

Here is the thing, and this is fundamental software architecture. You only need a database when it is time to persist something. So, what you need os a persistence service. Call it a database if you want, it can be as simple as a text file, as someone sugested.

Ironically the same set of rules that made your life easier as a developer, are making you confused. And questions arise. Specifically the question of what exactly happens when I close the program?

But the answer is dead simple. The requirements made it simple. If you close the application its gone. There is no persistence mechanism. This is actually super safe. No record, no proof. More importantly, its a requirement to be like so.

The problem, therefore, is you. You feel the need for persistence. You see an account and immediately place it in a database somewhere. You do a transaction, you feel the need to store it.

So what exactly happens when you persist something in a program? The program keeps all the information it needs to run. It may have gotten that information from a database, a user, or it may have randomly generated it. Who cares? All the program needs is the information in objects it knows how to use, in classes types and whatever more; in other words, in RAM. So persistence is taking things out of RAM into a less volatile storage.

But the real question is, how exactly does that affect the program? Does that cause any fundamental change?

For one the cashier operations are still the same. Prices must still be calculated, transactions must still be made, and all the rules associated must still be observed.

If something, there is less code involved. There is no solving the persistence problem. The information is volatile. Its a requirement to be so.

This is fundamentally the evolution process of a system under development, or even to some extent in production.

During development I care very little to store anything. What is actually usefull is to have reproucible state of the data. One I can interact with to make tests and verify that the software works (ie. it does not let me buy something if I have no money). This is easier done without any database system, specially the repoducible part.

Sure I can do backups of the data, but is it not easier to just restart the app? And where is the bug exactly if I need a specific database to see it? Is it in the code? Or is it a consistency issue in the database system? Probably the latter. How does that affect the cashier? It doesn't. Its a persistence detail. It has nothing to do with the business of a cashier.

I feel I have way more I could say, but I'm not sure where exactly you expect to get with this question. So I will stop here. Feel free to further inquire on this matter.